# Runtime error String(format: ) when passing less variadic parameters

Tags: ios, swift, string-formatting, apple-m1

Recently in firebase crashlytics we found out the following problem:

```swift
let a = "1-> %@" // Strings are located in Localized.strings, we already know them
let b = "1-> %@, 2-> %@" 

let aStr = String(format: a, "hello") // Works fine
let bStr = String(format: b, "hello") // Run time error on certain machine (M1, physical device)
```

Looks like when passing less variadic parameters into `String(format:)` you get runtime crashes on M1 and physical devices.

I was wondering if there is any way to avoid these runtime errors for the strings coming from `localised.strings`.

The best would be to catch this on compile time.
How would you face this problem?

Comment: Since the format comes from `localized.strings`, you should change the code example to look as close as possible to your actual code (i.e. `localizedStringWithFormat`, `NSLocalizedString` and all that good stuff). I don't think there is a way to check this with the compiler alone, but the compiler + a tool like `plutil -lint` + some custom scripts may provide a solution.

Comment: @SergeyKalinichenko I was basically thinking of code generation may be a solution. For every format string it will generate a function with exact number of parameters (avoid variadic). But then we have problem with different languages. But we can create different methods for different languages.

Comment: I think Bradley's answer gives you a good template for a solution then. Perhaps you would optimize it here and there, but the idea of building your own function to "front" the process of localization is the right idea. Perhaps you could push more parameters instead of asserting, to show question marks in place of unknown parameters, but the overall approach looks solid to me.

Comment: This is a good reason for not using `String(format:)`. In modern Swift there is no real reason to call it ever, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @matt So what should be used instead?

Comment: Well it depends why you're using it. In this case it looks like you're just doing some sort of string concatenation, so why not use simple concatenation with `+` or insertion with string interpolation? Or do a simple substitution. I mean, you are not actually _formatting_ anything here. Or if the real code is more interesting, show it.

Answer (score 1):

Not providing enough parameters to a format string will result in undefined behaviour (it might crash, it might not - there's no way to know).
It's a programming error but due to the dynamic nature of them, you won't get a compile-time warning at the moment.

However, writing a small helper we can deterministically crash if not enough format parameters are provided.
Note this is not a perfect implementation and may need tweaking to suit your requirements.

```swift
extension String {

    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string
    private static var formatCharacters: Set<Character> {
        "@diufFeEgGxXoscpaAn".reduce(into: []) { $0.insert($1) }
    }

    static func safely(format template: String, _ params: CVarArg...) -> String {
        var potentialPattern = false
        var patternCount = 0
        for char in template {
            switch char {
            case "%":
                // %% or %
                potentialPattern.toggle()
            case let x where formatCharacters.contains(x) && potentialPattern:
                patternCount += 1
                potentialPattern = false
            case let x where !x.isWhitespace:
                potentialPattern = false
            default:
                break
            }
        }
        assert(
            patternCount <= params.count,
            "Not enough parameters passed to format String. Found \(params.count), expected at least \(patternCount)."
        )
        return String(format: template, arguments: params)
    }
    
}
```

We then get a crash if not enough parameters are provided:

```swift
let f = String.safely(format: "%@ %@", "nice")
// Assertion failed: Not enough parameters passed to format String. Found 1, expected at least 2.
```

Comment: I was actually talking about strings that come from `localized.strings `. So we already know them. Sure dynamic strings cannot be compile time checked!

Comment: @KwnstantinosNikoloutsos Ah I see, take a look at my updated answer.